# Why do instance fields belong to the instances instead of their prototype?

Tags: javascript, class, field, prototype, language-design

In the JavaScript `class` syntax introduced in ES6 (*static* properties are accessible from the class, *instance* properties are accessible from the instances):

- static fields belong to the class;
- static methods belong to the class;
- instance methods belong to the instances’ prototype;
- `this` properties belong to the instances.

So I expected that instance fields would belong to the instances’ prototype, like instance methods. But that’s not the case, they get a special treatment and belong to the instances instead, like `this` properties.

For example, the class

```js
class A {
  static x;                   // static field
  static f() {}               // static method
  y;                          // instance field (special treatment)
  g() {}                      // instance method
  constructor() {this.z = 0}  // this property
}
```

gives the results

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A)
[ 'length', 'name', 'prototype', 'f', 'x' ]
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype)
[ 'constructor', 'g' ]
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new A)
[ 'y', 'z' ]
```

**Why do instance fields belong to the instances instead of their prototype?**

A drawback that I see with this special treatment is that it prevents one from simply declaring non-function properties in the instances’ prototype, forcing one to do it after class declaration (or resort to a static initialization block):

```js
> A.prototype.y2 = 0;
0
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype)
[ 'constructor', 'g', 'y2' ]
```

Another drawback is that if one wants to declare properties on the instances, there is already `this` for that, so it duplicates an existing language feature.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252932/discussion-on-question-by-gery-ogam-why-do-instance-fields-belong-to-the-instanc); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to the addition of public instance fields, those properties had always belonged to the instances <sup><sub>(except in some rather obscure usage)</sub></sup>. And after the addition, they kept storing those properties in the instances.

In section 2.1 of [this article by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](https://2ality.com/2019/07/public-class-fields.html), it shows the motivation for adding public instance fields.

> Sometimes, you have an assignment in a constructor that creates an instance property, but is not influenced by any other data in the constructor (such as a parameter)

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
}
```

> In such a case, you can use a field to move the creation of counter out of the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  counter = 0;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

So, the addition of public instances can simplify constructors. It also makes it clear that the initial value of a property does not depend on the arguments of the constructor. (It may also help readability and make it easier for documentation)

There is also a semantic difference, as class fields use the `[[DefineProperty]]` semantics (with a behavior that matches `Object.defineProperty`), so with public fields, the setter in a superclass will not be called.

Compare:

```js
class A {
  set prop(value) {
    console.log('SETTER: '+value);
  }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.prop = 123; // (setter will be called, inherited from A)
  }
}
console.log(new B); //does not contain a 'prop' field because there is a setter
```

with

```js
class A {
  set prop(value) {
    console.log('SETTER: '+value);
  }
}
class B extends A {
  prop = 123; //setter from A is not called
}
console.log(new B);
```

---

As for why those properties belonged to the instances rather than prototypes (also applicable in the days before `class`es became a thing in JS):

If you have a property in the prototype, once you assign, say, `instance1.property1 = 3`, the value from the prototype is no longer used (property shadowing); a new property is created in the instance and the value in the prototype is not changed. So putting a value in the prototype is not very useful.

In contrast, a method is usually not re-assigned, and it's useful to share between instances. `instance1.method1(...)` and `instance2.method1(...)` call the same function with different `this`. (So those are not aliases of each other as they have different effects).

Comment: "*those properties had always belonged to the instances.*" - well unless it had been created via `MyClass.prototype.counter = 0`. "*Putting a value in the prototype is not very useful.*" - it is occasionally useful as a default value. But I agree, this is rather obscure usage, mostly even the default was already created on the instance for simplicity (and also it's considered best practice to create all instance properties already during instantiation, not sometime later).

Comment: @Bergi Right. By "belonged to the instances", I meant that the most common practice was like `this.counter = 0` within the constructor

Answer (score 0):

`class` syntax was just a syntactic sugar for existsing things:

1. A `prototype` - an object with things shared between instances, mostly methods and get-set descriptors
2. A `constructor` - a function to make objects with predefined prototype
3. Using `constructor` as a namespace to keep related things
4. Fields? What fields? You just have an object with prototype, do whatever you want with it

`class` syntax included all that... with exception of constants on prototype - they have very weird behaviour (actually being property initializers) and noone really ever used them

Comment: "*they have very weird behaviour (actually being property initializers) and noone really ever used them*" - are you referring to "constants on prototype" or "class fields" there?

Comment: I think "fields" refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields), which is a pretty recent addition, and I hardly ever use it, but it's likely that many others find it useful.